# Xamarin forms jenkins build for android

Tags: jenkins, xamarin.android, continuous-integration

i'm trying to run jenkins job for xamarin.android for building APK,

here is the build commands

```
msbuild ${PROJECT_NAME}.sln \
 /t:${PROJECT_NAME}_Droid:SignAndroidPackage \
 /p:Configuration="Release"
```

the build is failing with the following error

```
 error MSB4057: The target "Sample_Droid:SignAndroidPackage" does not exist in the project.
```

my project name is sample, what is the solution for this error ?

Comment: any suggestions to build apk, i'm still not getting any solution for this

Answer (score 1):

got solution by changing msbuild target from .sln to .csproj

here is the solution command

```
msbuild $WORKSPACE/droid/${PROJECT_NAME}.Android.csproj \
 /t:${PROJECT_NAME}_Droid:SignAndroidPackage \
 /p:Configuration="Release"
```